# Is there a way to mix a class with a discriminated union in F#?

Tags: f#

I think it would be convenient to have a discriminated union type with an initializer.
My idea is to combine something like this:

```
type Result =
| Ok of string
| Error of int
```

With something like that:

```
type Result(someData) =
    if SomeData = true then
        this class is Ok "all good"
    else
        this class is Error 100
```

Is there some clever syntactic way to make an object that can take an input, run some logic and end up with several states that can be used directly in a match statement?

(or, if this idea is not good, I'd be happy to hear why too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea isn't feasible for discriminated unions because they are immutable structures, and only class types may take in constructors.

That said, there are alternatives.

**Shadowing**

```
type Result =
| Ok of string
| Error of int

let Result someData =
    if someData then
        Ok "all good"
    else
        Error 100
```

gets you the kind of semantics you'd expect.

**Factory method**

```
type Result =
| Ok of string
| Error of int with
    static member Create(someData) =
        if someData then
            Ok "all good"
        else
            Error 100
```

and then `Result.Create false`. You can have multiple overloaded factory methods.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Wlaschin suggests an interesting approach that I think deals with your requests. The basic idea is to define DU constructors as private inside a Module, so that the only way to create a type is by a custom "creation" function inside that module. I inserted Active Patterns in the example bellow to address your "can be used directly in a match statement" request:

```
module User =
    type UserID =
        private //this is important! prevents accessing the constructors outside this module
        | String10Constructor of string
        | String20Constructor of string

    let createUser s =
        if String.length s <= 10 then s |> String10Constructor |> Ok
        elif String.length s <= 20 then s |> String20Constructor |> Ok
        else Error "String lenght should be less than 21."

    let (|User10|User20|) = function
        | String10Constructor s -> User10 s
        | String20Constructor s -> User20 s

open User

let tryToCreateUser s = 
    match createUser s with
    | Ok u ->
        match u with
        | User10 s -> sprintf "User10: %s" s
        | User20 s -> sprintf "User20: %s" s
    | Error e -> e

tryToCreateUser "1111111254545454543345678911" //ouput: "String lenght should be less than 10."

tryToCreateUser "10" //ouput: "User10: 10"

tryToCreateUser "1044646546546466" //ouput: "User20: 1044646546546466"

//you cannot override createUser by trying to access the constructor directly
//(error: "not accessible from this code location)
    let x = String10Constructor ""
```